# Does Win32::OLE::Const->Load('Microsoft Excel'); depends on Excel version

Tags: perl, win32ole

I'm using `Win32::OLE::Const->Load()` in perl :

```
$xl = Win32::OLE::Const->Load('Microsoft Excel');
```

then I test if `scalar(keys %{$xl})` is zero :

```
 if (scalar(keys %{$xl})==0) {
        return False;
    }
    else {
        return True;
    }
```

I tested this code in machine which supports Microsoft Excel 2003 it gives `True`, but when I tested the same code in machine where there is Microsoft Excel 2013 it gives me `False`!

I also printed the `scalar(keys %{$xl}` in the first machine it gives 2023, in the second machine it is 0!

Best Regards

Comment: which version of `perl` are you using on the two machines?

Comment: @HåkonHægland in machine where there is Excel 2013 the version is (v5.26.3) MSWin64 in the other is (v5.16.3) MSWin32-x86

Comment: what does `print ref $xl,"\n"` give you?

Comment: @HåkonHægland it gives nothing, I also tried to print $xl in the machine where the keys are defined it gives HASH(...) in the other one it gives nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after searching I found the solution.

it gives 0 in the second machine cuz there is no win32 Excel key in the registre.

the solution is adding win32 key in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\1.8\0\`